# Adding quotation marks to string before calling a function

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, dapps, javascript, string

Alright, so I'm not sure if I should be asking this here or HTML/JavaScript forums, so please do let me know if I am in the wrong place. I believe it belongs here as you all understand dApps and Solidity.

How can I make it so that when an user inputs a string in my dApp, I add the double quotation marks to it before passing the string onto the smart contract's function?

So, what I have now is a dApp that uses the HTML `input` tag to gather a string that is a parameter of a function in my smart contract. However, for the calling of the function to work, I need to add double quotation marks to the string, so that the contract recognizes this.

I don't want users to have to add the quotation marks, so I'd like to "pre-add" them, either on HTML or JavaScript, without the user seeing them there. Any suggestions on how to do this? Current code below:

HTML input tag:

```
<input id="string" type="text">
```

JQuery code:

```
  $("#button2").click(function(web3) {
     var tx = Contract.function($("#string")[0].value, { 
         from: address,
         gas: "3000000",
         to: "Contract address here",
         value: "0",
         data: ""
  }, function(err, transactionHash) {
   if (!err)
        console.log(transactionHash); 
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var tx = Contract.function($("#string")[0].value,
```

To

```
 var tx = Contract.function("\"" + $("#string")[0].value + "\"",
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! I'm not too familiar with JavaScript so didn't know how to apply escape characters there.